# How do I select data inside a density curve in R?

Tags: r, select, kernel-density

I have a 2 varaible data set that I have to plot (na and ob). I applied the kde2d kernel and plotted  1 to 4 sigma density curves (confidencebound). I need to select those points that are inside 2 sigma curves (letting out all those between 1 and 2 sigmas), but not just in the plot, I neet select them from the data set, put them in a new list. Could you please help me with this?

```
kde_BPT <- kde2d(na,ob, n=1000, lims=c(-2,2,-1.5,1.5))
confidencebound <- quantile(kde_BPT$z, probs=c(0.685,0.955,0.9975,0.99995), na.rm = TRUE)
```

The data are to large to paste here. I put here the plot if that helps, I need to know which data points (any colour) are in the area between the contour curves of 1 and 2 (sigmas).

[The plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHRig.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will need to supply na and ob. Please do that using `dput` and pasting the results in your question.

Comment: Hello. The lists are too long and exceed the character limit for posting here. Is there a way to upload them as files ore something? Or should I post like half of the data? 

Thanks

Comment: I just added the plot if that helps.